# NetBeans auto import the path of javascript files

Tags: javascript, css, netbeans

I am developing web based software applications which means that the presentation layer is html pages.

Every html page needs to have imported javascript files (sometimes 10 to 15) and lots of css files (sometimes 20 to 30).

I find it really anoying to write the path to each one of them ( Well when you write the path to the first one then you can simply copy and paste it and change only the file name but this is not the case ). Ok... i was talking about that it is really annoying and time consumption.

Here is example:

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/styles.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../xxx/yyyy/zzz/a.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../xxx/yyyy/zzz/b.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../xxx/yyyy/zzz/c.css">  


    <script src="../xxx/a.js"></script>
    <script src="../xxx/yyy/zzz/b.js"></script>
    <script src="../xxx/yyy/zzz/c.js"></script>
    <script src="../xxx/yyy/zzz/d.js"></script>
```

So lets just ask you the question:

**Is there a way (or a plugin) in NetBeans which can help me to drag the file from its location (the project is visualized as a tree) and put it in the html so its path to be automatically inserted in the file?**

Comment: I asked this question two weeks ago but no answer is introduced yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know this is an old post but as of recent versions of NetBeans, drag the file from the tree into the document itself, and it will place a  tag to the CSS file automatically.

Cheers